# Light PHP framework with smarty and Friendly URL

Tags: php, templates, frameworks, smarty, friendly-url

I'm looking for light PHP framework (without complex architecture, mvc/mvvm, etc) with smarty support.

But also I want to friendly url. For example, request `http://www.myhost.com/somepage` should load smarty-template `somepage.tpl`. Are there some standard solution?

Comment: What have you found so far? SO isn't here to Google things for you.

Comment: If you are just starting something, I wouldn't use smarty :X Just said. But @topic: Yes, there are solutions. There are many solutions.

Comment: @JamWaffles Of course here is not Google, but here, supposed to be, the place of professionals and experts.

Comment: @sємsєм, thank you. I worked with different php frameworks, I know different programming patterns, but I needn't it in my current task. I  need very light stupid solution for small site without coolness things with support template system and friendly URL. But google cann't help me.

Comment: @sємsєм Professionals and experts, however, research their problem or requirement before blindly asking for the assistance of others.

Comment: @JamWaffles Why do we reinvent the same wheel while some one else, probably, know it? This what I exactly mean.

Comment: @DreamWalker In this case, and for long term usability, I think that you have to create your own PHP framework. This tutorial may be useful: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-a-php5-framework-part-1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go for CodeIgniter With Smarty Template... Its very light and url-friendly..and it is very easy to code for MVC Beginners,

Documentation is very clear and simple for CodeIgniter,

[CodeIgniter Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)

Look into following link to know how to integrate smarty with CodeIgniter,

[Integrating Smarty with CodeIgniter](http://www.coolphptools.com/codeigniter-smarty)

Comment: I hear about many light weight frameworks, but the one I really tested is CodeIgniter. Also CodeIgniter community is large enough to respond to your major technical issues. Its documentation is wonderfully organized.